# How do you split a string into quoted sentence and numbers using python

Tags: python, string, split

Hi guys I am new to python and would appreciate some help!

I have multiple strings like this:

```
21357.53 84898.10 Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course 80912.48 84102.38
```

And I am trying to figure out how to split the line based on a group of words (ie. `"Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course"`) with quotes around it and the doubles without quotes.

I am then rearranging the strings to be in this format:

```
"Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course" 21357.53 84898.10 80912.48 84102.38
```

to rearrange I would just use

```
for row in data:
    outfile.write('{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}'.format(row[2], row[0], row[1], row[3], row[4]))
    outfile.write('\n')
```

But I'm just not sure how to get a single quoted sentence out of the line. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So you mean there must be 2 float numbers before and another two after, in this format, `float float string float float`?

Comment: Please post some more lines to clarify the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I would do that:

```
import re

tgt='21357.53 84898.10 Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course 80912.48 84102.38'

nums=[m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'[\d\.]+',tgt)]
words=[m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'[a-zA-Z]+',tgt)]
print '"{}" {}'.format(' '.join(words),' '.join(nums))
```

Prints:

```
"Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course" 21357.53 84898.10 80912.48 84102.38
```

Alternatively, you can test what Python thinks is a float to find them:

```
nums=[]
words=[]
for e in tgt.split():
    try:
        nums.append(float(e))
    except ValueError:
        words.append(e)

print words,nums
```

Finally, if you have the fixed format of 4 floats and a string (float,float,string,float,float) you can do:

```
li=tgt.split()
nums=' '.join(li[0:2]+li[-2:])
words=' '.join(li[2:-2])
print words,nums
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
s = "21357.53 84898.10 Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course 80912.48 84102.38"
sList = s.split(' ')
words = []
nums = []
for l in sList:
    if l.isalpha():
        words.append(l)
    elif l.isdigit():
        nums.append(l)

wordString = "\"%s\"" %  " ".join(words)
row = [wordString] + nums
```

At this point, `row` contains the row that you want.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name >:-(

Comment: No, `.isalpha()` fails on space characters. However much I like simple `.split()`, here a regexp seems a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

Code using regular expression:

```
import re

s = '21357.53 84898.10 Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course 80912.48 84102.38'
row = re.search('([0-9.]+)\s([0-9.]+)\s([\w ]+)\s([0-9.]+)\s([0-9.]+)', s)
if row:
    print '"{0}" {1} {2} {3} {4}'.format(row.group(3), row.group(1), row.group(2), row.group(4), row.group(5))
```

Will print (with double quotes):

```
 "Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course" 21357.53 84898.10 80912.48 84102.38
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `str` methods:

```
>>> s = '21357.53 84898.10 Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course 80912.48 84102.38'
>>> temp = s.split()
>>> temp
['21357.53', '84898.10', 'Mckenzie', 'Meadows', 'Golf', 'Course', '80912.48', '84102.38']
>>> row = [temp[0], temp[1], '"'+' '.join(temp[2:-2])+'"', temp[-2], temp[-1]]
>>> row
['21357.53', '84898.10', '"Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course"', '80912.48', '84102.38']
>>> print '{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}'.format(row[2], row[0], row[1], row[3], row[4])
"Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course" 21357.53 84898.10 80912.48 84102.38
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how long is the string, it matters that there must be 2 float number both before and after the string. So I asked in the comment. I use `temp[2:-2]`. @AshwiniChaudhary

Answer (score 0):

Using [`str`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) methods, [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), and [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
>>> words = "21357.53 84898.10 Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course 80912.48 84102.38".split()
>>> print '"%s" %s'%(" ".join(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), words)), " ".join(filter(lambda x: not x.isalpha(), words)))
"Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course" 21357.53 84898.10 80912.48 84102.38
```

More strictly, without assuming all non-alpha words are floats (uses [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)):

```
>>> words = "21357.53 84898.10 Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course 80912.48 84102.38".split()
>>> print '"%s" %s'%(" ".join(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), words)), " ".join(filter(lambda x: reduce(lambda y, z: z.isdigit() and z, x.split('.'), True), words)))
"Mckenzie Meadows Golf Course" 21357.53 84898.10 80912.48 84102.38
```